# AWS Lambda OpenAi Twitter Bot Python

Tags: python, aws-lambda, twitter, tweepy, openai-api

```
def tweet_mood(sign, mood):
    tweet = f"{sign}: {mood}"
    if len(tweet) <= 280:
        response = client.create_tweet(text=tweet)
        tweet_id = response.data.id
    else:
        tweets = [tweet[i:i+277] + "..." for i in range(0, len(tweet), 277)]
        tweet_id = None
        for t in tweets:
            if tweet_id is None:
                response = client.create_tweet(text=t)
                tweet_id = response.id
            else:
                response = client.create_tweet(text=t, in_reply_to_tweet_id=tweet_id)
                tweet_id = response.id
    return tweet_id
```

I want it to send tweets that do not fit in 280 characters as a tweet thread.
but my code is giving error
"[ERROR] AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'"

I don't know how to code or program.
I am trying to learn something by developing a project.

I was progressing smoothly until I got to this stage. It sends a tweet but does not create a tweet thread.

The problem is definitely related to "response.id" but I can't find a solution.

The bot I'm trying to do enters a promt on openai and tweets the incoming response. Due to the 280 character limit, I couldn't get the exact result I wanted, so I'm trying to create a tweet thread.